# How to find same filename but different content

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files, directory

I am trying to find the textfiles that have the same name but contain different content from two different directories.

The following is my code but it keeps crashing here

```
cati=`ls $1 | cat $i`

catj=`ls $2 | cat $j`
```

etc...

How can I correct it?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
    echo "Usage ./search.sh dir1 dir2"
    exit 1
elif [ ! -d  $1 ];then
    echo "Error cannot find dir1"
    exit 2
elif [ ! -d  $2 ];then
        echo "Error cannot find dir2"
        exit 2
elif [ $1 == $2 ];then
    echo "Error both are same directories"

else
    listing1=`ls $1`
    listing2=`ls $2`
    for i in $listing1; do
            for j in $listing2; do
                if [ $i == $j ];then
                     cati=`ls $1 | cat $i`
                     catj=`ls $2 | cat $j`
                     if [ $cati != $catj ];then
                           echo $j
                     fi
                fi

            done
    done
fi
```

Comment: Unrelated but worth mentioning: instead of explicitly typing out `./search.sh` in the usage, use `$0` instead. It will always be expanded to how you type it on the command line. So even if the filename changes, it will accurately reflect the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using `find` and a `while read loop`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Set a trap to clean up temp files.
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT

##: Create temp directory using mktemp.
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit

##: If arguments less than 2
if (( $# < 2 )); then
  printf >&2 "Usage %s dir1 dir2 \n" "${BASH_SOURCE##*/}"
  exit 1
fi

dirA=$1
dirB=$2

##: Loop through the directories
for d in "$dirA" "$dirB"; do
  if  [[ ! -e $d ]]; then  ##: If directory does not exists
    printf >&2 "%s No such file or directory!\n" "$d"
    exit 1
  elif [[ ! -d $d ]]; then  ##: If it is not a directory.
    printf >&2 "%s is not a directory!\n" "$d"
    exit 1
  fi
done

##: If dir1 and dir2 has the same name.
if [[ $dirA = $dirB ]]; then
  printf >&2 "Dir %s and %s are the same directory!\n" "$dirA" "$dirB"
  exit 1
fi

##: Save the list of files in a file using find.
find "$dirA" -type f -print0 > "$tmpdir/$dirA.txt"
find "$dirB" -type f -print0 > "$tmpdir/$dirB.txt"


##: Although awk is best for comparing 2 files I'll leave that to the awk masters.

while IFS= read -ru "$fd" -d '' file1; do  ##: Loop through files of dirB
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file2; do ##: Loop through files of dirA
    if [[ ${file1##*/} = ${file2##*/} ]]; then  ##: If they have the same name
      if ! cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"; then ##: If content are not the same.
        printf 'file %s and %s has the same name but different content\n' "$file1" "$file2"
      else
        printf 'file %s and %s has the same name and same content\n' "$file1" "$file2"
      fi
    fi
  done < "$tmpdir/$dirA.txt"
done {fd}< "$tmpdir/$dirB.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! I found a way to correct mine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome "newuserr"!  I think the main issue here is trying to load the entire file into a shell variable.  Firstly, that won't scale well.  Second, the comparison won't work great because of the changes made by the backticks as the file is being read into the shell.  And finally, all of the whitespace in the file is going to break your code.  But there are ways around all of this! :)

You can get use the return value from `diff` and avoid reading the files into the shell at all.  Like so:

```
if diff $i $j; then
     echo $j
fi
```

Some other suggestions:

- It is a good idea to use `[[` over `[` for doing conditionals in the shell.  The `[[` deal better with messing items.
- What sort of missing items?  What if `$i` or `$j` were empty?  Then the shell would error out on that line.  You can force the shell to keep a place for the missing variable by doing `"$i"` or `"$j"`.
- [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will read your code and make suggestions for best practices.
- [google's shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) has lots of other tips.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find a way to correct it based on your suggestions :)